# cannot find org.slf4j.Logger and use log.info() etc

Tags: maven, spring-boot, slf4j, lombok

IDE: Intellij IDEA 2018.3
project only one module

dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I can use `@Slf4j` but why cannot find `Logger`

[image: cannot find Logger]

[image: cannot use log.info() etc...]

[image: already open annotation processor]

Comment: If you want to use SLF4J you will have to add that depenency as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below dependency in your pom file. You are missing dependency. To use the slf4j logger its respective dependency should be present. Hope this solves your problem.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.24</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.24</version>
</dependency>
```